# Webfonts: Why aren't my fonts showing?

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

Fonts were working, but stylesheets were messy and static assets were being served by application server. When I moved the assets to CloudFront, my fonts stop working. I have created a https://jsfiddle.net/Lunhdb62/ to exemplify the issue:

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue Std 35 Thin';
    src: url(http://d39wu5b1mi9u0h.cloudfront.net/assets/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Th-cbecc0396d9eccbbeff4a92e06449eb1.woff) format("woff"),
         url(http://d39wu5b1mi9u0h.cloudfront.net/assets/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Th-94816ab73b42e623ce8fdd576647dbff.ttf) format("truetype");
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue 75 Bold';
    src: url(http://d39wu5b1mi9u0h.cloudfront.net/assets/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd-4f24f787ae7577c7b0f8392ae2a62ad6.woff) format("woff"),
         url(http://d39wu5b1mi9u0h.cloudfront.net/assets/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd-4c5729a69333fbd9dfb4907d8eab440b.ttf) format("truetype");
}

p {
    font-size: 32pt;
    font-family: monospace;
}
p.normal {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue 35 Thin';
}
p.bold {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue 75 Bold';
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>monospace</p>
<p class="normal">Helvetica Neue Light</p>
<p class="bold">Helvetica Neue Bold</p>
```

Additional question: Does the 'font-family' I choose in the @font-face declaration matter? Or it can be anything I want?

Comment: Your fonts are not loaded on jsfiddle because jsfiddle uses https but fonts use http protocol. On chrome 41, I'm getting security error and fonts are not loaded.

Comment: In addition, this might be an issue for you application server too.

Comment: Apparently the issue is loading the fronts form another host, I try https (as CloudFront allows) but fonts won't load still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your font family names differ for your thin font type:
`Helvetica Neue Std 35 Thin` in the declaration and `Helvetica Neue 35 Thin` for the actual use.

Second: Your font locations should be inside quotations: `'http://d39wu5b1mi9u0h.cloudfront.net/assets/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Th-cbecc0396d9eccbbeff4a92e06449eb1.woff'`

And third, you can't @font-face to fonts hosted on a different domain. Browsers won't allow this. You'll have to host the fonts on the same domain and declare your path from there.

Comment: Thanks, I created a new JSfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/7bdnksxd/) addressing some of the issues. Ultimately, I think my problem is using a different host or CDN as @Aaron points out in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience loading fonts from a CDN causes problems in IE and FF, problem being they won't load. I've tried multiple fixes for this but non worked for me, in particular this fix by David Walsh http://davidwalsh.name/cdn-fonts .

As for the `font-family:` you can use any name you like for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer on `font-family`, I'm a backend developer trying to do some front end, I appreciate the help!